# Is the article 'a' in "How many petition a player can file?" correct usage?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-article

Is this sentence is correct or not?

> How many petition a player can file?

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not correct.

**How many petitions {can a player file}?**

You needed to invert the subject-verb order of the {marked clause} (and enlist an auxiliary verb).

> What time {does the train depart}?
>
> When {will you come home}?
>
> What food {does the iguana eat}?
>
> How much wood {can a woodchuck chuck}?

P.S. But your use of the article **a** is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The article "a" is correct, because it goes with "player"; you are talking about any single player.

However, there are two mistakes in your sentence:

- "how many" has to go with a plural, so you need "petitions" rather than "petition"
- the "can" needs to be moved to the front of the phrase "a player can file" when you make it a question, so "can a player file"

> How many petitions can a player file?

Note that without the question mark, the word order would be valid; for example in a list of key facts, you might write:

> How many petitions a player can file: 10

Which is another way of saying:

> Number of petitions a player can file: 10